# Missing Account Links in Mobile Menu Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am not getting how the contents of my account links are not displaying when viewed as mobile format. You can see in the image there is no links under account tab. 
I'm using **porto theme**

[image]

```
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="porto_newsletter_popup" template="subscribe_popup.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_custom_notice" template="html/custom_notice.phtml" after="-"/>
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_sidebar_sticky" template="html/sidebar_sticky.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">

        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="porto_header" template="html/header.phtml" before="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">

                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Form\Login" name="header_customer_form_login" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/login_popup" template="Smartwave_Porto::html/login.phtml"/>

            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />

            <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_block" template="html/header_custom_block.phtml" ifconfig="porto_settings/header/static_block" after="-"/>

             <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="header_login" template="Smartwave_Porto::html/headerlogin.phtml"/>
        </block>

    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="minicart" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="currency" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
    <move element="skip_to_content" destination="porto_header"/>

    <move element="page.top" destination="page.wrapper" after="porto_header"/>

    <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="1"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="1"/>

    <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="header.links">
        <block class="Smartwave\Porto\Block\Template" name="custom_link" before="-" template="html/custom_link.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
```

**Js**

$('.panel.header.header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\.links'); });